# How to fix the openvpn service Error opening configuration file on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, services

I experience a frustrating behaviour of openVPN used as a Windows 10 service:
it doesn't start, and when you look at the log it tells:

```
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\xxx.ovpn
Use --help for more information.
```

But the openvpn GUI works with the **same** configuration file!
Unfortunately, the --help doesn't help.
What can I do to at least have more diagnostic details?
Thanks
Alexandre

Comment: You could try Process Monitor to check why OpenVPN service can't open the file.

Comment: Thanks Montonero.  
It is hard to decipher. I can see that `bitdefender`is sometimes involved, but I cannot determine whether it is generating a conflict.

Comment: You'll need to include only OpenVPN service process in a procmon's filter. That will make things much easier.

Comment: I did initially, but unfortunatelly, it does not give me a better hint that the previous one regarding `bitdefender`.  
I can only suppose that `bitdefender` is restricting the access to the `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was desperately simple: 
**remove the encrypt attribute on the file**.

Apparently, `openvpn` as a command can decrypt the files, but as a service it cannot.

Answer (score 1):

What is the command line the service uses to launch OpenVPN?

If it looks something like this:

```
openvpn C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\xxx.ovpn
```

OpenVPN (usually) needs to be launched in the directory where all of its authentication files are (unless you specified an absolute path to them; like `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\ta.key`) Try adding `--cd C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\` to the command line, so that it looks more like this:

```
openvpn --cd C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\ --config C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\xxx.ovpn
```

If that doesn't help, try adding `--verb 11` to the command line and showing us the output of that.

## EDIT

The OpenVPN page on [Running OpenVPN as a Windows Service](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-as-a-windows-service/) shows that the `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpnserv2.exe` is a service wrapper that launches the main OpenVPN executable. I have two suggestions:

1:
Use `regedit` to show us the settings the wrapper is using (the page mentioned above has information on the registry values), and modify them appropriately.
2:
Write your own batch script that launches OpenVPN and set that as the executable launched by the service. I would prefer the former of these two, as it is the least invasive.

Comment: Thanks Shadowcoder  
But there is no command line. It is launched as a service whose main executable is located at `"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpnserv2.exe"`.  
I suppose that the problem is related to _some_ rights, but couldn't find out which.

Comment: Looks like you might have to go poking around in the registry or reconfigure the service to launch OpenVPN without the service wrapper. Read my edits above

Comment: Your answer helped me because I did some tries changing the file name in the registry. It guided me to look at the attributes of the config file, and when I removed the `encrypt attribute`, it worked.

Thanks again Shadowcoder.